# How to transfer field location inside a div?

Tags: 8, entities

[image]

I am looking for a way to transfer the location of the field created programmatically inside a div created by field_group module.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Go to manage manage form display and move it below the group parent

Comment: @NoSssweat If you create the field in an alter_hook is this possible?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer yea, as long as you do `$form['parent_name']['field_name']`

Comment: @NoSssweat this is new for me, I will test it tomorrow.

Comment: I am not able to target the machine name of the field_group

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using javascript:

```
<script>
$("#edit-field-date").appendTo("#detail-wrap");
</script>
```

But I am still looking for a way to do it under form_alter.